# [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Request failed with status code 404]

Tags: javascript, openai-api

When I do the following:

```
const completion = await openai.createCompletion({
  model: "gpt-3.5-turbo-0301",
  prompt: 'my prompt'
});
alert(completion.data.choices[0].text);
```

I get the following error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Request failed with status code 404]
at node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:null in createError
at node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:null in settle
- ... 11 more stack frames from framework internals
```

But if I do `model: text-davinci-003`, it works. How can I use the gpt-3.5-turbo model?

Comment: what are your valid models? https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/models/list

Answer (score 0):

The model `gpt-3.5-turbo-0301` is not supported for **Completion** but only for **ChatCompletion**.

If you make the corresponding raw HTTP request you should receive the following 404 error message.

```json
{
  "error": {
        "message": "This is a chat model and not supported in the v1/completions endpoint. Did you mean to use v1/chat/completions?",
        "type": "invalid_request_error",
        "param": "model",
        "code": null
    }
}
```

This is a correct way to use this model for chat completion.

```js
const completion = await openai.createChatCompletion({
  model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages: [{role: "user", content: "Hello world"}],
});
console.log(completion.data.choices[0].message);
```